# Android Studio - Rearranging XML in code style not working

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, reformatting

So I'm trying to configure in `Settings--> Code Style --> XML` how I would like the order of the attributes to be sorted when reformatting the code using ctrl+shift+L on Windows. 
In my case, first all `xmlns` and other namespace attributes and then all the specific views attributes.
In order to do so, I tried playing with the rules preconfigured in the code style settings, and also by creating new rules.
By default, first `xmlns` tags are shown, then view attributes, and then `tools:...`, as shown in the image here:
[image] 
When going to  `Settings--> Code Style --> XML`, I tried playing with the preconfigured rules and even tried creating a new rule, but didn't manage to get the `tools:...` attributes to be displayed after the `xmlns` attributes.
This is an image of the code style settings screen, also with the rule, I tried to create.
[image]
Just to make sure, this is what I'm trying to achieve:
[image]
I also trying going over and over the documentaion but couldn't quite figure out how to properly create the rule, since it's not working.
[XML code style documentaion](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/code-style-xml.html)
Has anyone tried changing these settings, and/or can help me with the setting?

Thank you

Comment: Is it `CTRL+ALT+L` or `CTRL+SHIFT+L` like you have saidi\ cause I always use the first one!

Comment: @Xenolion Doesn't really matter since the keyboard shortcut can be changed and may have been and I don't remember doing so. 
Bottom line is that I want to rearrange the code and sort the order of the attributes to my liking when reformatting using the keyboard shortcut.

Comment: I did not even if they are can be customized!

Answer (score 5):

Found the answer:
1. Add a new rule
2. In my case:
`Name = tools:.*`
`Namespace = .*`
3. Done!

Answer (score 0):

In the same place, `Settings--> Code Style --> XML` **Set** default settings from Android profile.

**Wrong setup**

[image: Wrong setup]

**After reimporting default settings** `(Set From -> Android)`

[image: After reimport default settings]